# Выдернуть ВСЕ значения атрибута bigimg используя BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Назрел такой вопрос. Только начал изучать питон, используя библиотеку `BeautifulSoup` задался вопросом. Есть HTML код, к примеру:

```
<a>
 <img src="/uploads/201103/thumb-img/MY-520-Nebulizer-Atomized-Inhaler-thumb-G-44318.jpg" width="42" height="42" imgb="uploads/201103/goods-img/MY-520-Nebulizer-Atomized-Inhaler-G-mid-44318.jpg" alt="MY-520 Portable Ultrasonic Nebulizer Atomized Inhaler 520" bigimg="/uploads/201103/source-img/MY-520-Nebulizer-Atomized-Inhaler-G-44318.jpg" />
</a>
<a>
 <img src="/uploads/201103/thumb-img/MY-520-Nebulizer-Atomized-Inhaler1298912536346-thumb-P-44318.jpg" alt="MY-520 Portable Ultrasonic Nebulizer Atomized Inhaler 520" imgb="/uploads/201103/goods-img/MY-520-Nebulizer-Atomized-Inhaler1298912536380-P-44318.jpg" width="42" height="42" bigimg="/uploads/201103/source-img/MY-520-Nebulizer-Atomized-Inhaler1298912536529-P-44318.jpg" />
</a>
```

Мне нужно выдернуть все ссылки на большие изображения, которые находятся в атрибуте `bigimg=`.

Написал такую строчку:

```
itemImages = soup.find("div", "scrollableDiv").findAll("img")
```

но как выдернуть именно ВСЕ значения атрибута `bigimg` не представляю.
Может быть кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, буду признателен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению не знаю библиотеку beautiful soap , но знаю как решить вашу проблему регекспами.

допустим весь хтмль код у вас содержится в переменной **html**

```
import re
big_imgs = re.findall(r'bigimg="(.*?)"', html)
```

в big_imgs у вас массив со всеми значениями внутри bigimg.

например если бы приведены вами хтмль код засунуть в переменную **html**

```
>>> big_imgs = re.findall(r'bigimg="(.*?)"', html)
>>> big_imgs
['/uploads/201103/source-img/MY-520-Nebulizer-Atomized-Inhaler-G-44318.jpg', '/u
ploads/201103/source-img/MY-520-Nebulizer-Atomized-Inhaler1298912536529-P-44318.
jpg']
```

Comment: Именно так и было сделано, но хотелось все средствами beautiful soap выполнить...

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы найти все элементы с bigimg атрибутом и "выдернуть" его значение:

```
 bigimgs = [tag['bigimg'] for tag in soup.find_all(bigimg=True)]
```

Comment: @СашаЧерных у меня в профиле почта, пишите. Не обещаю ответить, но я всё читаю.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте **soupselect**. С помощью неё очень удобно работать с BeautifulSoup.

http://code.google.com/p/soupselect/

В интернете много примеров использования.